# Find UTC Offset given a city

Tags: winapi, timezone, utc, offset

In C++ on Windows, given a city, lets say london or newyork or sydney or singapore etc.. how do I find the UTC offset for each of them, ie the function should be able to accept a city name and return the UTC offset in the current scenario ie taking into account daylight savings. Any ideas how this can be done using win32 APIs

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want an API for searching the [zoneinfo / tz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) database..?

Don't know if there is a library with precisely the interface you want.  But reading it and searching it yourself would not be difficult.  It's just a [flat file database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database), text with one record per line.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone.tab

Comment: More specifically, can I get the timezeone the city is currently observing given the city name in windows?